# csslint warning Fallback background (hex or RGB) should precede RGBA background." evidence="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

Tags: csslint

csslint warning Fallback background (hex or RGB) should precede RGBA background." evidence="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);/* FF3+,Saf3+,Opera 10.10+,Chrome,IE9*/
Despite i have given a fallback.
Its giving many warning and i have fixed many and its not showing warning for them but now when i am fixing rest of it it is still giving me warning no matter how many times i cleared cache and re-ran and re-fixed the same thing.

```
      background: #000;
    background: transparent;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#cc000000,endColorstr=#cc000000);/*IE 5.5-7*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#cc000000,endColorstr=#cc000000)";/*IE8*/
    zoom: 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got the issue the 
Its still a parser problem 
here is a link 
https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/issues/370

```
background: #000000;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
background: transparent;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4c000000,endColorstr=#4c000000);/*IE 5.5-7*/
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4c000000,endColorstr=#4c000000)";/*IE8*/
zoom: 1;
```

the above order works